# Класс array, ошибка при запуске

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <time.h>

    using namespace std;

    class Demo{
        int size = 0;
        int arr[];  
    public:
        Demo() {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                arr[i] = 0;
        }

        Demo(int i) :size(i){
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                arr[i] = rand() % 10;
        }

        void show(){
            for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
                cout << arr[i] << ' ';
            cout << '\n';
        }
    };

    int main(){
        Demo a(5);

        a.show();

        return 0;
    }
```

Помогите разобраться, при запуске появляется [ошибка](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdpKZ.png) и пишет что объект a повреждён!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++ (9.2 Class members)

> 9 Non-static (9.4) data members shall not have incomplete types.

Данное объявление члена данных `arr`

```
int arr[];
```

является неполным, так как размер массива неизвестен. И кроме того объявление массива не может содержать нулевой размер. 
Поэтому само определение вашего класса является некорректным.

Вам следует либо самостоятельно динамически создавать массив в зависимости от задаваемого значения его размера, либо использовать уже готовый класс `std::vector<int>`.

Если вам для учебных целей нужно поработать с динамическим распределением массивов, то объявление класса может выглядеть следующим образом (я не включил в него конструктор перемещения и оператор перемещения)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class Demo
{
private:    
    size_t size = 0;
    int *arr = nullptr;  

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef int value_type;

    Demo() = default;

    Demo( size_t i ) : size( i ), arr( i == 0 ? nullptr : new int[i] )
    {
        if ( arr )
        {
            std::generate( arr, arr + size, [] { return std::rand() % 10; } );
        }
    }

    Demo( const Demo &rhs ) : size( rhs.size ), arr( rhs.size == 0 ? nullptr : new int[rhs.size] )
    {
        if ( arr )
        {
            std::copy( rhs.arr, rhs.arr + rhs.size, arr );
        }
    }

    ~Demo() { delete []arr; }

    Demo & operator =( const Demo &rhs )
    {
        Demo tmp( rhs );
        swap( tmp );

        return *this;
    }        

    void show() const 
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i ) std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void swap( Demo &rhs )
    {
        std::swap( size, rhs.size );
        std::swap( arr, rhs.arr );
    }

    size_type get_size() const { return size; }
};

void swap( Demo &lhs, Demo &rhs )
{
    lhs.swap( rhs );
}    

int main() 
{
    std::srand( ( unsigned int )std::time( 0 ) );

    Demo a1( 5 );
    Demo a2( 10 );

    a1.show();
    a2.show();

    swap( a1, a2 );

    a1.show();
    a2.show();
}
```

Программа может иметь следующий вывод на консоль:

```
1 8 5 1 2 
7 3 1 4 2 9 2 9 9 4 
7 3 1 4 2 9 2 9 9 4 
1 8 5 1 2
```

Что касается конструктора перемещения и оператора перемещающего присваивания, то они могут выглядеть следующим образом

```
Demo( Demo &&rhs ) : Demo()
{
    swap( rhs );
}        

Demo & operator =( Demo &&rhs )
{
    swap( rhs );

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: @Ilya Tikhonov Смотрите мое обновленное сообщение.